# Verbs of senses in progressive tenses

Tags: sense-verbs

How would a native speaker deal with this sentence

> I have seen him fight for his employees, I have seen him fight for his
>   company, and now I am seeing him fight for our country.

Is that childish? Is that an attempt to sound like a common citizen?
Is that grammatically correct at all?
Or maybe that one has a meaning available only to a native speaker?

Comment: What exactly are you asking? Do you have any specific reason for thinking the text might be ungrammatical? Do you not understand it?

Answer (score 1):

The contrast is between "I have seen him fight" and "I am seeing him fight". Although the continuous is not so common with verbs of seeing, hearing etc., in this context it seems to have been chosen because the simple present "I see him fight" could also imply habitual fighting. I don't think the present continuous is incorrect in this sentence, but the simple present "see" would also be possible. Maybe it's part of a general trend (like the slogan "I'm loving it").